# Kendo UI Dropdownlist: how add new elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

How can I add a new item in a Kendo DropDownlist, if it doesn't exist in the datasource?

Example: the Kendo DropDownlist shows some predefined values, but the user should also be able to add a new item by writing in an input text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `add()` method of the Kendo `datasource` to add new items:

```
var ddl = $("#dropDownListID").data("kendoDropDownList");
var dataSource = ddl.dataSource.add({
    "text": "new Item", 
    "value": 1000});
```